# E1700001 Negotiate Authentication Failed: 'No valid credentials provided'

Tags: java, svn, netbeans

Currently I am attempting to commit my Java project files via Subversion.

I am trying to do this through Netbeans 8.0, but whenever I enter my credentials I receive the following error:

```
org.apache.subversion.javahl.clientexception: svn: e170001: negotiate authentication failed: 'no valid credentials provided'.
```

I have looked around quite a bit for a solution to this, but I did not find any that really helped. My log file is listed below. Thanks for any help.

```
  INFO [org.netbeans.modules.subversion]: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
    org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:62)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:175)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication$1.run(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:166)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.authenticate(DefaultHTTPNegotiateAuthentication.java:221)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:450)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:371)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:359)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:710)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:627)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:102)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1020)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:182)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.getRevisionNumber(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:118)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnRepositoryAccess.getLocations(SvnRepositoryAccess.java:182)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.ng.SvnNgRepositoryAccess.createRepositoryFor(SvnNgRepositoryAccess.java:45)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:46)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.remote.SvnRemoteGetInfo.run(SvnRemoteGetInfo.java:31)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc2.SvnOperationRunner.run(SvnOperationRunner.java:20)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperationFactory.run(SvnOperationFactory.java:1149)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc2.SvnOperation.run(SvnOperation.java:294)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.info2(SVNClientImpl.java:1472)
    Caused: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E170001: Negotiate authentication failed: 'No valid credentials provided'
    at org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException.fromException(ClientException.java:68)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1293)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.info2(SVNClientImpl.java:1474)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getInfo(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2142)
    Caused: org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.SVNClientException
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.javahl.AbstractJhlClientAdapter.getInfo(AbstractJhlClientAdapter.java:2156)
    at org.tigris.subversion.svnclientadapter.AbstractClientAdapter.getInfo(AbstractClientAdapter.java:310)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler.handle(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:449)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:404)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnClientInvocationHandler.invoke(SvnClientInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.getInfo(Unknown Source)
    [catch] at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.ui.wizards.repositorystep.RepositoryStep$RepositoryStepProgressSupport.perform(RepositoryStep.java:229)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnProgressSupport.performIntern(SvnProgressSupport.java:111)
    at org.netbeans.modules.subversion.client.SvnProgressSupport.run(SvnProgressSupport.java:104)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1423)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

Comment: SVNKit does not support Negotiate and Kerberos authentication. SVNKit is used in Netbeans to access SVN repositories by default. Switch to native SVN client using JavaHL instead of SVNKit.

Comment: @bahrep, Thank you very much, the switch worked.

Comment: I'm going to add this as the answer in such case.

Comment: That works. It has been accepted as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVNKit does not support Negotiate and Kerberos authentication. SVNKit is used in Netbeans to access SVN repositories by default. Switch to [native SVN client using JavaHL](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqSvnJavahl) instead of SVNKit.

See the article [KB145: Troubleshooting Integrated Windows Authentication errors in the Eclipse IDE](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00145/) to learn more about the problem and resolution steps. The article is about resolving the problem in Eclipse, but should also work for Netbeans (however, step-by-step instructions won't work I guess).